# Spring API Produce JSON or XML

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I need to create an API that can produce either XML or JSON.
So for example if the path requested is

> /getData?format=XML

it should produce XML and if the path requested is

> /getData?format=JSON

is should produce JSON.

I've gone through the Spring tutorial ["Build a RESTful web service"](http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)
So I simply want to take that code and alter it so it will produce XML as well as JSON.

What are the steps I should take?

Comment: [This](http://theblasfrompas.blogspot.in/2013/10/spring-mvc-rest-content-negotiation.html) might help you

Comment: Why not just use the `Accept` header? This is the specific problem it's for, and Spring MVC has built-in support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1**: Make sure you have **Jackson 2** and **Castor** on the classpath for JSON and XML rendering respectively.  If using Maven, these can be added as dependencies.  You can also use GSON for JSON and JAXB for XML.

**Step 2**: Return a Java object from the controller method, something like:

```
@RequestMapping("/users")
public @ResponseBody Users all()
{
  return ServiceLocator.findUserService().all();
}
```

**Step 3**: Configure the JSON and XML converters in the Spring application context file as follows:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="prettyPrint" value="true" />
            <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
        </bean>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller" />
            </constructor-arg>
            <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/xml" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

**Step 4**: Configure a `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` in the Spring application context file as follows:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

---

Once these steps have been completed, different representations can be obtained in multiple ways:

**XML**

1. `http://server/users.xml`
2. `http://server/users?format=xml`
3. `http://server/users` with the HTTP header `Accepts` set to `application/xml`

**JSON**

1. `http://server/users.json`
2. `http://server/users?format=json`
3. `http://server/users` with the HTTP header `Accepts` set to `application/json`

Comment: You could also use [jackson-dataformat-xml](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml) for XML.

Comment: XML option number 3 should read `application/xml` instead of `text/xml`.